# ImageButton Transparency after zoom out

Tags: android, transparency, android-imagebutton, alpha-transparency

I use the following code to have `imageButton` with zoom ability.

```
<com.vatsal.imagezoomer.ImageZoomButton
                    android:id="@+id/novice_worker"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha=".35"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/novice_worker" />
```

Using the https://github.com/code-crusher/Image-Zoomer library i got the zoom effect as i want. My only problem is with the zoom-in and zoom out i loose the transparency (android:alpha=".35") until i go to another activity and come back to the one with the buttons. As i use many `imageButtons` in this activity that i change transparency programmatically in an if statement, is there a way to keep the `imagebutton` transparent in zoom?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because In that Library, they create new ImageButton from your so, all property will be reset.

Comment: Yea i imagine that. So i need a trick to have the transparency back. I m thinking if its possible to have a selector that sets transparensy (alpha .35) on pressed as i dont want to use image. I couldn find how to set alpha atribute in xml selector. And i dont know if this will work.

Comment: but Why use Library. Use ObjectAnimator to animate it.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya  I want to zoom image cause i have 30 small images. Library is the best solution i found. And do exactly what i want and as i want it, except the transparency.

Comment: so, use library code and modify it according to your need.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Yea, thanks for the effort, actually this is what i need to do. I dont know how to do it as i just need to set alpha 0,35 somewhere in library code. I tried to find it in the library code at android studio with no result. I found the place that says about alpha in library's code but its read only!